Effect of relaxing RHS of constraints in a convex optimization problem
I have a convex optimization problem of the form:
\begin{align}
\min\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} \quad&f(x)\\
\text{s.t. } \quad & g_i(x) \leq b_i, \forall i\in [m]
\end{align}
Let the primal-dual solution of the above be $(x^*,\lambda^*)\in \mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m_{\geq 0}$. It is known that the optimal dual variables $\lambda^*_i > 0$ for $i\in S \subseteq [m]$ (although it is possible that the dual optimum could be positive on indices outside of $S$). Now consider a perturbed version of the above problem: for some $\epsilon > 0$, consider:
\begin{align}
\min\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} \quad&f(x)\\
\text{s.t. } \quad & g_i(x) \leq b_i, \forall i\in [m]\setminus S\\
& g_i(x) \leq b_i + \epsilon, \forall i \in S
\end{align}
Let the solution of the above perturbed problem be $(x^\epsilon,\lambda^\epsilon)$. I am stating my question in two different, but related ways:

Under what conditions, if any, does the solution of the perturbed problem violate all the constraints in $S$ in the original problem?
Does there exist $\epsilon > 0$, alongside additional conditions, such that $g_i(x^\epsilon) > b_i$ for all $i\in S$? If so, what are these additional conditions?

Motivation: I am working on a learning-based method to remove constraints from convex optimization problems by learning the dual variable. One way of ensuring robustness against mispredictions by the learning-based method is to check, post-hoc, whether certain constraints are violated. The above question would be essential to the development of such robustness guarantees.
Addendum: Also assume that Linear Independence Constraint Qualification (LICQ) holds at the optimum of the original problem, although I'm not sure this assumption would be useful.
